# jQuery - How to added validate same input name into rules methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Before this, I'm so sorry for the basic question on this. But, I really got stuck with this. Below code is what I have tried so far but it's not working.

```
<form id="order_form">
  <input type="text" name="order_amount" id="order_amount"/>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" value="60" name="timer-radio"/>
    <input type="radio" value="90" name="timer-radio"/>
    <input type="radio" value="120" name="timer-radio"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<script>

var validator = $('#order_form').validate({
  rules: {
    order_amount: {
      required: true,
      min: 1,
      max: currentBalance,
    }
  },
  messages: {
    order_amount: {
      required: 'Order Amount Required',
    },
    timer-radio: {
      number: true
    },
  },
  errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element);
  },
  highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).addClass('error');
  },
  submitHandler: handleSubmitOrder,
});

function handleSubmitOrder(_, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

So, How can I add rules for radio input?

Comment: You're not even showing any attempt to validate the radio inputs.  *"it's not working"* is also not an acceptable problem description. Please refer to the help section for how to write a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind to avoid `-` in the input name i.e `timer-radio` when using jQuery Validate - use `timer_radio`. Otherwise for radio group you can just specify the name of the inputs of in the group. See also how easily you can place the error container after all the radio button inputs.

To avoid extra problems, your submit button shouldn't have name `submit` but something else, in case you will use `form.submit()` in validator submit handler on success.

```js
function handleSubmitOrder(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

$(function(){

  var validator = $('#order_form').validate({
    rules: {
      order_amount: {
        required: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 100
      },
      timer_radio: {
        required: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      order_amount: {
        required: 'Order Amount Required'
      },
      timer_radio: {
        required: 'Selection Required'
      },
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
      var group = element.attr('name') == 'timer_radio'?element.siblings().last():element;
      error.insertAfter(group);
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
      $(element).addClass('error');
    },
    submitHandler: handleSubmitOrder
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="order_form">
  <input type="text" name="order_amount" id="order_amount"/>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" value="60" name="timer_radio"/>
    <input type="radio" value="90" name="timer_radio"/>
    <input type="radio" value="120" name="timer_radio"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What's with the `e.preventDefault()` function?  In this context, there is no event tied to `e`.  Secondly, the plugin already blocks the default submit event as part of the internal `submitHandler` function.  I know the OP had something similar, but if you're going to show him how to do it correctly, please don't repeat the mistakes.